# BASH - Storing stdin reference '&0' in variable

Tags: bash, redirect, stdin

Trying to read from a file OR stdin, I wish to do something like this:

```
if [ "$1" == "-" ]
  then 
    INPUTFILE="&0"
fi
```

But if I do

```
while read ROW
  do
    # ... something
done <$INPUTFILE
```

I got

```
&0: No such file or directory
```

From the command line

```
cat <&0
```

works perfectly, is there a way to store the stdin reference in a variable?
PS: I know same result can be achieved in a simple way...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are occasions when `cat` has its uses, and this could be one of them:

```
# Use cat so it works if $1 is just -
cat $1 |
while read ROW
do
    ...whatever
done
```

Document why you are using `cat` like this; otherwise, it looks like a UUOC (Useless Use of Cat).

Comment: +1 Cleanly handles the case where `$1` is guaranteed to contain either a file name or standard input.

Comment: It (`cat $1`) also works in the case where there is no `$1`, of course, reading standard input again.  If you're guaranteed a file name or dash but the file name might contain spaces, you'd use `cat "$1"`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not working because the shell interprets `&0` as the filename.

Instead of saying:

```
INPUTFILE="&0"
```

say:

```
INPUTFILE="/proc/$$/fd/0"
```

This would make it read from the `STDIN` of the current shell process.

Comment: Yes, I didn't think to use /proc.

Comment: Non-Linux users should be advised that `/proc` may not be available.

Comment: @chepner I must say that you continue to enlighten us all.

Comment: As @Bruno pointed out, maybe the shortest way (Linux users) would be use of `/dev/stdin` .

Answer (score 0):

`&0` isn't a file name, but it's part of the notation for I/O redirections using file descriptors: you should read `<&0` as a whole.

You can find more details in [this document](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).

Comment: I know it isn't a file name, I was wondering if there were a way to store stdin in a var, as @devnull told me ;)

Comment: Ah, there's also `/dev/stdin`, `/dev/stdout` and `/dev/stderr` you can use as files.